# Quartz.NET how to get result when task is failed or successfull

Tags: c#, async-await, quartz.net

How to get information if task is finished successfully in the next example:
application creates random number between 1 and 10 each 5 seconds. If the number is 5 than return true, otherwise false. Here is the what i have done so far:

```
        public static async void Operate()
        {
            CreateScheduler();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MyFirstJob>()
                .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1")
                .Build();


            // Trigger the job to run now, and then every 5 seconds
            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
                    .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

            await _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        }

 class MyFirstJob : IJob
    {
        public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            bool retVal = false;

            var myTask = new Task(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    int num = rnd.Next(1, 11);

                    Console.WriteLine("Generated num:" + num);

                    if (num != 5)
                    { 
                        if (context.RefireCount < 6)
                        {                         
                            Console.WriteLine("Failed!");
                            throw new NotImplementedException();
                        }
                    } 

                    Console.WriteLine("OK");
                    retVal = true;


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            });


            myTask.Start();
            return myTask;
        }

        }
```

Is this good approach?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider the built-in capabilities Quartz.NET has. Generally you shouldn't start new tasks from jobs, they are the task. Consider just writing your logic with regular idiomatic task constructs, like await etc, then add separate listener to check for problems. Quartz.NET itself retries jobs on exceptions based on your configuration.

So far you haven't described why you want the exception information.

Comment: I wanted through expection detect if there was something wrong with execution. What will happen if job takes to much time to process something? Suppose that job ib triggered every 5 seconds but for some complex data processing or calculations the execution takse much more time, more than 5 seconds. How to detect if job is completed and it's ready for new exection?

Comment: If you job doesn't have DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute and current execution has exceeded interval, there will be two jobs running at the same time. These things should be covered quite well in documentation and FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

For a regular `Task` object, you can rely on wrapped Exceptions to determine failure.

Alternatively, you can return a `Task<T>` object to store a typed return value of your choice.

[Microsoft Docs - Task of T](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Example:

```
Task<bool> myTask = Task.Run(() => { return true; } );
var success = myTask.Result; // warning: this is a blocking call
```

Comment: in my case i can detect inside Exception that condition is not satisfied but how to return this back to the main thread?

Comment: Task<T> is what to use when you want tasks to store return values. You may have to switch some of your Task return types to a version of Task<T> and pass them back up the call chain to whoever needs the information.